# How to remove some items from a relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, object

I am loading data from two models, and once the data are loaded in the variables, then I need to remove those items from the first relation, that are not in the second one.

A sample:

```
users = User.all
articles = Articles.order('created_at DESC').limit(100)
```

I have these two variables filled with relational data. Now I would need to remove from `articles` all items, where `user_id` value is not included in the `users` object. So in the `articles` would stay only items with `user_id`, that is in the variable `users`.

I tried it with a loop, but it was very slow. How do I do it effectively?

**EDIT:**

I know there's a way to avoid doing this by building a better query, but in my case, I cannot do that (although I agree that in the example above it's possible to do that). That thing is that I have in 2 variables loaded data from database and I would need to process them with Ruby. Is there a command for doing that?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `belongs_to` relation on the `Article` model:

```
articles.where.not(users: users)
```

This would give you at most 100, but probably less. If you want to return 100 with the condition (I haven't tested, but the idea is the same, put the conditions for users in the where statement):

```
Articles.includes(:users).where.not(users: true).order('created_at DESC').limit(100)
```

Comment: Thanks @nikkon226, I know there's a way to build a better query, but I already have the data in the variables and need to process them (I update the OP).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would probably be with a SQL join. Would this work?

```
Articles.joins(:user).order('created_at DESC').limit(100)
```

Comment: Thanks @JoshBodah, I know there's a way to build a better query, but I already have the data in the variables and need to process them (I update the OP).

Comment: I assume the issue is that the naive solution of just iterating over the collection and doing an `.include?` check is too slow because of the size of `users`. Some other options you have are to 1) sort `User.all` by `id` and use binary search (Array#bsearch) 2) use Sets to find the intersection 3) iterate while inserting into a Hash to memoize your work between iterations (e.g. iterate over articles and check if user_id in hash else search users while caching each in the hash). The binary search approach is okay (Set might do okay too), but the Hash way could be slow